# MySQL & PHP - Best way to get a list of descending count of countries from database table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compile (to display in a web page) a list of countries and the counts from a MySQL DB. The entries are in a table and I need to display on a page the list of countries in the DB, in order of how many entries there are.

So I know how to get a list of countries from the database with, for example,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE country_code='GB'
```

And I know how to get a list of countries with, for example,

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_code FROM table_name;
```

But I am struggling to put it all together and get a list of only the countries that are actually in the DB, then their count and then put them in descending order.

Looking for a gentle nudge in the right direction to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
COUNT(*),
country_code
FROM table_name
GROUP BY country_code
```

`GROUP BY` is what you need for this type of problem.

You can add an `ORDER BY` to the end of the query, if necessary.

Comment: I think, renaming the column generated by COUNT(*)  would make the query result neater.

Comment: @Willem Renzema Thank you for your reply. This works, but how would I order then by the actual count per country? I need to order the results by the highest number of entires per country, so for example, in the order of GB=10, US=5, ES=1, but this result gives me a list of each country and the count per country (which is correct), but how would I order them in this way?

Comment: Got it, just add ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC at the end! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select count (*), country_code from (SELECT DISTINCT country_code FROM table_name)
```

But the proper way is using `GROUP BY`

```
select count(*), country_code 
from table_name
group by country_code
```

To get them ordered by date for ex, you do:

```
select count (*), country_code from 
(SELECT DISTINCT country_code 
 FROM table_name
 order by date
)
```

Or (by using group by):

```
select count(*), country_code 
from table_name
group by country_code
order by date
```